# Using custom locks to insert rows safely

Tags: mariadb, innodb, upsert, locks

I basically need an UPSERT functionality where a row is created once a day and updated from then on until the next day. From a business perspective, there must be *one or zero rows per day*.

My problem obviously being concurrency and two sessions creating that one row simultaneously.

As I understand, `SELECT ... WHERE day = today FOR UPDATE` does not prevent a second session from instantly also getting a (0 rows) result, if that row does not exist.

I created a table just for the purpose of locking a certain 'resource' e.g. `SELECT * FROM my_semaphore WHERE resource = 'daily' FOR UPDATE` and then proceed to do my actual business logic on the other tables (that I don't need to lock now). The row with `resource = 'daily'` definitely exists, so I know every other sessions, that wants this resource needs to wait until the first session commits their transaction.

Is there a smarter approach, am I missing something?

Comment: If you describe what you are actually using this OneRow per Day for, maybe someone would come up with a better way of getting the result you want completely

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a primary key for the `day`-column and the update functionality adds value to your day-row, you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (day, value) 
VALUES(current_date(), YOURVALUE) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value + YOURVALUE;
```

Comment: thanks @slaakso, but I want/need to handle all the logic on the application level. Also there is no (composite)key within the where condition. the per day example was just one of many. At the end of the day I want to upsert safely from the application

Comment: That table needs `PRIMARY KEY (day)` so that upsert knows which row to use.  If it is actually "per day per person", then have a composite PK and mention both columns in the upsert.

Comment: @FriedrichRoell. You should handle the atomic operations in the db side instead of trying to invent the wheel with own semaphores et al.When you ask the question, it’s better to be specific with the actual case you have in hand. Otherwise you will not get the answers that  would help you.

Comment: `day` can also be a `UNIQUE KEY`. Databases are good at atomic operators with years of experience from talented developers to make them fast and accurate. Leverage this as best you can.